# How to mock asyncio coroutines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, python-asyncio

The following code fails with `TypeError: 'Mock' object is not iterable` in `ImBeingTested.i_call_other_coroutines` because I've replaced `ImGoingToBeMocked` by a Mock object.

How can I mock coroutines?

```
class ImGoingToBeMocked:
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def yeah_im_not_going_to_run(self):
        yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
        return "sup"

class ImBeingTested:
    def __init__(self, hidude):
        self.hidude = hidude

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def i_call_other_coroutines(self):
        return (yield from self.hidude.yeah_im_not_going_to_run())

class TestImBeingTested(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_i_call_other_coroutines(self):
        mocked = Mock(ImGoingToBeMocked)
        ibt = ImBeingTested(mocked)

        ret = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(ibt.i_call_other_coroutines())
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since `mock` library doesn't support coroutines I create mocked coroutines manually and assign those to mock object. A bit more verbose but it works.

Your example may look like this:

```
import asyncio
import unittest
from unittest.mock import Mock


class ImGoingToBeMocked:
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def yeah_im_not_going_to_run(self):
        yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
        return "sup"


class ImBeingTested:
    def __init__(self, hidude):
        self.hidude = hidude

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def i_call_other_coroutines(self):
        return (yield from self.hidude.yeah_im_not_going_to_run())


class TestImBeingTested(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_i_call_other_coroutines(self):
        mocked = Mock(ImGoingToBeMocked)
        ibt = ImBeingTested(mocked)

        @asyncio.coroutine
        def mock_coro():
            return "sup"
        mocked.yeah_im_not_going_to_run = mock_coro

        ret = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
            ibt.i_call_other_coroutines())
        self.assertEqual("sup", ret)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Well this is obvious and now I feel dumb for asking the question!  Thanks!

Comment: I expanded this with with a helper and stuff in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29905620/23972

Answer (score 16):

I am writting a wrapper to unittest which aims at cutting the boilerplate when writting tests for asyncio.

The code lives here: https://github.com/Martiusweb/asynctest

You can mock a coroutine with `asynctest.CoroutineMock`:

```
>>> mock = CoroutineMock(return_value='a result')
>>> asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(mock)
True
>>> asyncio.iscoroutine(mock())
True
>>> asyncio.run_until_complete(mock())
'a result'
```

It also works with the `side_effect` attribute, and an `asynctest.Mock` with a `spec` can return CoroutineMock:

```
>>> asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(Foo().coroutine)
True
>>> asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(Foo().function)
False
>>> asynctest.Mock(spec=Foo()).coroutine
<class 'asynctest.mock.CoroutineMock'>
>>> asynctest.Mock(spec=Foo()).function
<class 'asynctest.mock.Mock'>
```

All the features of unittest.Mock are expected to work correctly (patch(), etc).

Answer (score 14):

Springing off of Andrew Svetlov's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29892903/23972), I just wanted to share this helper function:

```
def get_mock_coro(return_value):
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def mock_coro(*args, **kwargs):
        return return_value

    return Mock(wraps=mock_coro)
```

This lets you use the standard `assert_called_with`, `call_count` and other methods and attributes a regular unittest.Mock gives you.

You can use this with code in the question like:

```
class ImGoingToBeMocked:
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def yeah_im_not_going_to_run(self):
        yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
        return "sup"

class ImBeingTested:
    def __init__(self, hidude):
        self.hidude = hidude

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def i_call_other_coroutines(self):
        return (yield from self.hidude.yeah_im_not_going_to_run())

class TestImBeingTested(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_i_call_other_coroutines(self):
        mocked = Mock(ImGoingToBeMocked)
        mocked.yeah_im_not_going_to_run = get_mock_coro()
        ibt = ImBeingTested(mocked)

        ret = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(ibt.i_call_other_coroutines())
        self.assertEqual(mocked.yeah_im_not_going_to_run.call_count, 1)
```

Comment: +1 for the `wraps` keyword, which did make me understand its purpose a bit more. Quick follow up question; how would you go about returning more than one value from a mocked coroutine? i.e. `read()` is a coroutine and you want to first return some data `b'data'`, and then return an EOF-like condition (e.g. no data, `b''` or `None`). AFAICS you can't use `.return_value` or `.side_effect` on the mocked coroutine (gives a `bad yield` error).

Answer (score 7):

You can create asynchronous mocks yourself:

```
import asyncio
from unittest.mock import Mock


class AsyncMock(Mock):

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        sup = super(AsyncMock, self)
        async def coro():
            return sup.__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return coro()

    def __await__(self):
        return self().__await__()
```

Answer (score 5):

A slightly simplified example for python 3.6+ adapted from a few of the answers here:

```
import unittest

class MyUnittest()

  # your standard unittest function
  def test_myunittest(self):

    # define a local mock async function that does what you want, such as throw an exception. The signature should match the function you're mocking.
    async def mock_myasync_function():
      raise Exception('I am testing an exception within a coroutine here, do what you want')

    # patch the original function `myasync_function` with the one you just defined above, note the usage of `wrap`, which hasn't been used in other answers.
    with unittest.mock.patch('mymodule.MyClass.myasync_function', wraps=mock_myasync_function) as mock:
      with self.assertRaises(Exception):
        # call some complicated code that ultimately schedules your asyncio corotine mymodule.MyClass.myasync_function
        do_something_to_call_myasync_function()
```

Comment: This answer worked best for my use case, but doesn't this only work with python3.8+? AFAICT this only works because of the addition of [AsyncMock](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.AsyncMock) in 3.8. (Note that the docs for [patch](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) state that "the target is replaced with an AsyncMock if the patched object is an async function".)

Answer (score 4):

### New in Python 3.8 [AsyncMock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.AsyncMock)

> **Setting the spec of a Mock, MagicMock, or AsyncMock to a class with**
> **asynchronous and synchronous functions will automatically detect the**
> **synchronous functions** and set them as MagicMock (if the parent mock is
> AsyncMock or MagicMock) or Mock (if the parent mock is Mock). **All**
> **asynchronous functions will be AsyncMock**.

```
class ExampleClass:

    def sync_foo():
        pass

    async def async_foo():
        pass


a_mock = AsyncMock(ExampleClass)
a_mock.sync_foo
>>> <MagicMock name='mock.sync_foo' id='...'>
a_mock.async_foo
>>> <AsyncMock name='mock.async_foo' id='...'>

mock = Mock(ExampleClass)
mock.sync_foo
>>> <Mock name='mock.sync_foo' id='...'>
mock.async_foo
>>> <AsyncMock name='mock.async_foo' id='...'>
```

**Special Attributes for AsyncMock:**

- [assert_awaited](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.AsyncMock.assert_awaited)
- [assert_awaited_once](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.AsyncMock.assert_awaited_once)
- [assert_awaited_with](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.AsyncMock.assert_awaited_with)
- [assert_awaited_once_with](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.AsyncMock.assert_awaited_once_with)
- [assert_any_await](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.AsyncMock.assert_any_await)
- [assert_has_awaits](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.AsyncMock.assert_has_awaits)
- [assert_not_awaited](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.AsyncMock.assert_not_awaited)
- [reset_mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.AsyncMock.reset_mock)
- [await_count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.AsyncMock.await_count)
- [await_args](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.AsyncMock.await_args)
- [await_args_list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.AsyncMock.await_args_list)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [asynctest](https://pypi.org/project/asynctest/) and import `CoroutineMock` or use `asynctest.mock.patch`

Answer (score 2):

Dustin's answer is probably the right one in the vast majority of cases. I had a different issue where the coroutine needed to return more than one value, e.g. simulating a `read()` operation, as briefly described in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881236/how-to-mock-asyncio-coroutines#comment48364349_29905620).

After some more testing, the code below worked for me, by defining an iterator outside the mocking function, effectively remembering the last value returned to send the next one:

```py
def test_some_read_operation(self):
    #...
    data = iter([b'data', b''])
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def read(*args):
        return next(data)
    mocked.read = Mock(wraps=read)
    # Here, the business class would use its .read() method which
    # would first read 4 bytes of data, and then no data
    # on its second read.
```

So, expanding on Dustin's answer, it would look like:

```py
def get_mock_coro(return_values):
    values = iter(return_values)
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def mock_coro(*args, **kwargs):
        return next(values)

    return Mock(wraps=mock_coro)
```

The two immediate downsides I can see in this approach are:

1. It doesn't allow for raising exceptions easily (e.g. first return some data, then raise an error on second read operation).
2. I haven't found a way to use the standard `Mock` `.side_effect` or `.return_value` attributes to make it more obvious and readable.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a bunch of answers here already, but I'll contribute my expanded version of [e-satis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34828288/122763). This class mocks an async function and tracks call count and call args, just like the Mock class does for sync functions.

Tested on Python 3.7.0.

```py
class AsyncMock:
    ''' A mock that acts like an async def function. '''
    def __init__(self, return_value=None, return_values=None):
        if return_values is not None:
            self._return_value = return_values
            self._index = 0
        else:
            self._return_value = return_value
            self._index = None
        self._call_count = 0
        self._call_args = None
        self._call_kwargs = None

    @property
    def call_args(self):
        return self._call_args

    @property
    def call_kwargs(self):
        return self._call_kwargs

    @property
    def called(self):
        return self._call_count > 0

    @property
    def call_count(self):
        return self._call_count

    async def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._call_args = args
        self._call_kwargs = kwargs
        self._call_count += 1
        if self._index is not None:
            return_index = self._index
            self._index += 1
            return self._return_value[return_index]
        else:
            return self._return_value
```

Example usage:

```py
async def test_async_mock():
    foo = AsyncMock(return_values=(1,2,3))
    assert await foo() == 1
    assert await foo() == 2
    assert await foo() == 3
```

Comment: I tried that, but I got: `ValueError: a coroutine was expected, got <_GatheringFuture pending>` while using it in `asyncio.gather(AsyncMock())`

Comment: `AsyncMock` acts like a _coroutine function_, but `gather` expects a coroutine. You probably need an extra set of parentheses, like `asyncio.gather(AsyncMock()())`.

Comment: What about `from asynctest import CoroutineMock`

Comment: With an extra set of parenthesis I get `TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable`

Comment: I put a reproducible code here: https://github.com/Martiusweb/asynctest/issues/114

Comment: I found out, that, for some reasons, it is crashing with `asyncio.run` while working with `loop.run_until_complete` — https://bugs.python.org/issue36222

Comment: All this is because gather returns a future not a coroutine.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `Mock` to act like a coroutine function:

```
class CoroMock(Mock):
    async def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(CoroMock, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _get_child_mock(self, **kw):
        return Mock(**kw)
```

You can use `CoroMock` pretty much like a normal mock, with the caveat that calls will not be recorded until the coroutine is executed by an event loop.

If you have a mock object and you want to make a particular method a coroutine, you can use `Mock.attach_mock` like this:

```
mock.attach_mock(CoroMock(), 'method_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fake type of [AsyncMock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.AsyncMock)

```
import asyncio
from types import CoroutineType
from unittest.mock import AsyncMock

task = AsyncMock(spec=CoroutineType)
asyncio.iscoroutine(task) # True
```